# Maven: bundle specific dependency

Tags: maven

Imagine you have environment-specific build which results into two bundles: Home and Office.  Environment-specific artifact of your build depends on some common artifact, lets call it 'Core'. It is just a common functionality for Home and Office builds. Home artifact depends on Core, and Office artifact depends on Core. In fact, Home and Office can even be the same artifact which is just build under different Maven profiles:  in case we call Maven with -pHomeBundle it builds artifact one way, in case with -pOfficeBundle - it builds it for office, both times taking Core as a dependency which is the same as for Home.

So far so good.

Now a question is: what can we do if Core artifact, which is common for Home and Office bundles has dependencies on other artifacts which are DIFFERENT for Home and Office bundles? I.e. Core artifact is not bundle-dependent, but its dependencies are.

How can we provide our Core with this dependencies?

How can we write Core POM for this?

UPDATE
Two solutions were suggested for this problem: add two bundle-specific dependencies to Core project as provided (and then add one real in the bundle-specific module Home/Office which takes Core as a dependency), or add two real dependencies to Core module and then filter them in the bundle-specific module Home/Office.
But I cannot get with which dependency Core will be build. No matter we provide it or not - it should be build with some dependency because it goes to repository. As far as I understand it will just take the first available class and use it. So I will have a Core artifact built using one of the dependencies.

Comment: Can't you add both dependencies as provided in Core pom.xml... and add the specific dependency for Home or Office in its pom files? so Home pom file has a dependency for the artifact that Office doesn't have

Comment: Be aware of the caveats when using profiles this way: [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2, Caveats](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html#Caveats).

Comment: fmodos, a question is how Maven can build Core if Core depends on something which is unknown at them moment of build (at the moment when we build core we dont know which bundle - Home or Office - we will build after). Looks like this is impossible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would prefer to have those bundle specific dependencies added in their respective pom.xml and exclude them under the core dependencies so that I am 100% sure of getting only those dependent libraries added for that project.

We have encountered a similar situation in our application when we had to build the same application for two different runtimes and some framework libraries had the runtime libraries bundled in them. So we ended up excluding them from the core dependency and included them as individual dependencies to the application POM.

Hope this makes sense and also helps. Curious to learn if legends have a better approach.

Comment: Raghav, you mean add BOTH to core POM, and then exclude one redundant in parent application POM?

Comment: As per your example .. i meant adding all dependencies to home and office project pom(dependencies of core jar + core dependency itself) and under the core dependency in home and office pom exclude all dependencies of the core ..  with this you are explicitly adding the dependencies of core in home and office pom and you can also control what version / flavor of dependencies are getting used.

Comment: Raghav, a question is which dependency will be used while compiling the Core module. Core must be compiled with some determined dependency. If both are added into dependencies - which one will be used?

Comment: @Dymytry See [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.5.2. Project Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html): _"When a project specifies a parent, it inherits the information in the parent project’s POM. It can then override and add to the values specified in this parent POM."_

Comment: I second Gerold .. However @Dymytry the core will get compiled with the version of dependencies added in the respective Home / Office pom xml. Cos you would want the Core to be compiled with the version of libraries that also are compatible with Core's children or dependant module - Home / Office. Maven does it this way !!

Comment: Raghav, but core may be compiled without knowing about Home and Office. Because it is a separate artifact and separate maven problem. Thats the problem, looks like we cannot solve it :/

Comment: I don't think you still got what I was trying to say ... core can be a project on its own and get built independent of home and office .. but what you care is when you run home or office you want the right dependencies home or office needs .. so the solution I suggested should work .. it's feasible to have two different runtime dependencies but not two compile time dependencies so what I said will still work ... i think you should try once before thinking it won't work ..

Comment: @Dymytry "below" and "above" can change here at SO, depending on your sort criterion top-right above the answers section: _active_, _oldest_, _votes_. There's a [share link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413699/1744774) below each answer to refer absolute rather than relative.

Comment: Raghav, looks like I got it. Yes it will work. But I just want you to confirm that we understand it the same way: core will be compiled with one of the home/office dependencies and used (possibly) with another one. As far as I know its ok if there are no public final static fields, inlined by compiler.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like things have gotten a little confused here. You should never really build an environment specific version of your app. You should build only one app, and it should work in any suitable environment, be it home or office. The things that are different should be provided by the environment.

Let's get concrete.

For example: you depended on an oracle database at work, and a mysql database at home. You build your software against a standard interface, say JPA. Your home and work containers (let's assume tomcat), should have a properties file containing the database connection string in a jar in its `provided` library folder. Then, when your app starts, it can pick up the environment's database. One app, multiple environments.

Another example: you depend on log4j while at home, but in the office auditing is more rigorous than that and you have to use a custom library. Your code is built against a standard logging interface, and your container at home has the log4j libraries in the `provided` folder, when your app is deployed at home it'll pick up the log4j implementation, but your `provided` folder at work has the custom logging library so that when your app is started there it picks that up instead.

Hopefully, you can see from these examples that the software we build should be given an environment with environment specific implementations of the services it expects. With modern java, osgi, and modern containers, this is always true. We can always build our software this way. We should not need nor never have environment specific builds.

If you have functionality that's different in each environment, then strip it out into a separate module and mark it as provided in the modules that use it. Usually this will result in at least three modules, one for the interface, and two for environment specific implementations. The interface is almost always a runtime dependency, and the implementations are almost always provided.

Answer (score 1):

Re *"Home and Office can even be the same artifact"*

Do you mean building `office` and `home` (snapshot or release) with the same GAV *and* jar file name but with different profiles?

Since a picture is worth a thousand words is it that what you want to achieve:

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  office-for-core:jar                      office:jar     
                     \                    /                 office build 
                      \                  /
 - - - - - - - - - - - (office-)  - - - / - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                                core:jar                     core build
 - - - - - - - - - - - - (home-)  - - - \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                        /                \
                       /                  \                  home build
      home-for-core:jar                    home:jar
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Yes exactly that what I am talking about! Thanks for picture, Gerold Broser!

Comment: And there is a separate maven build for core.jar

Comment: @Dymytry You're welcome. (I love ASCII art :-) May i ask you to answer my question as well?

Comment: Geri, I meant building Home and Office with the same group:artifact but with different versions. I dont want Office to erase Home in Nexus. This can be archieved in two ways: separate Maven projects with same group:artifact but different versions, or one Maven artifact built with different profiles which modify its version.

Comment: @Dymytry I see. But with GA(2V) you have to keep track (externally) which version is for what. Technically it's possible, of course, but I'd consider this inconvenient and likely to confuse your users and possibly developers you share your projects with. There are good reasons why it's called artifact**Id** and why IDs are considered to be unique.

Comment: Yes, may be its better to change it to different artifact names. But whatever we write in artifact name, it is not solving the issue I have asked about :/