# Organizing environment-specific builds with Maven and Teamcity

Tags: maven, version-control, teamcity

We have one project which builds are environment-specific. Now this results in two branches of development with massive dublication of functionality. The two resulting artifacts with the same name and different versions are build with TeamCity from two different branches and deployed to Nexus. We want to create one branch of development from these two branches.

The idea is straight-forward: create one Maven project which filters the dependencies and settings by Maven profile. Resulting artifact will be supplied a version which depends on profile. We are going to create two TeamCity builds which will run same Maven command but with different profiles, and build same artifact with different versions, and both builds will operate from the same VCS branch.

Is this a normal, typical, working setup for our use case?
Is it ok to have two builds based on one branch, no conflicts because of target folder etc?
Is it ok to build the same artifact with two versions simultaneously with TeamCity?

Comment: Best practice is to build a single artifact and promote it between environments. Anything specific to the environment should be external to the application and should be provided by the environment. The problem with what you're describing is testing -- you test the modified-for-this-env version, and then release the untested not-modified-for-this-env version. You end up testing something different from the production build.

Comment: Plus: what you're suggesting would be extremely difficult to configure with profiles, because version is a higher-level concept -- profiles exist within a version of a pom.

Comment: Plus: what you're discussing isn't versioning -- versioning applies to revisions of a single code-base. You're talking about different implementations for different environments -- that's not versioning, and you shouldn't try to solve this problem with versioning.

Comment: See [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html) and read the _Caveats_ section at the end carefully.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, why I "test the modified-for-this-env version, and then release the untested not-modified-for-this-env"? If I change something related to both environments I will retest the build with both profiles.

Comment: Build single artifact is a great idea. I would call it 'core' artifact. But there is a problem: my 'core' artifact may depend on environment-specific artifacts which I cannot unite by now. I have asked a question about this, but looks like there is no solution. @GeriBroser has painted a great scheme of this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392144/maven-bundle-specific-dependency